# Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-image-builder

This `Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput` command on Powershell 7.3 returns this error:

```
$ArtifactId = (Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput -ImageTemplateName $imageTemplateName -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup).ArtifactId


 The term 'Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Running `Install-Module AzureRM` doesn't help.

What do I need to install to get `Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput`.

Comment: Have you got to check this command Get-AzImageBuilderTemplateRunOutput which is the latest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment with same commands and got same error:**

**Console:**

[image]

The command **`Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput`** is previous version of the documentation, The latest command is **[Get-AzImageBuilderTemplateRunOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/powershell/module/az.imagebuilder/get-azimagebuildertemplaterunoutput?view=azps-9.1.0)**

**Command:**

```
Get-AzImageBuilderTemplateRunOutput -ImageTemplateName < Template name > ResourceGroupName  < resource grp name >
```

**Console:**

Before using command, please make sure you have installed module **`Az.ImageBuilder`** in your environment.

**Command:**

```
Install-module -Name Az.ImageBuilder
```

[image]